# Idle Disconnect while running cell Google Colab

Tags: cloud, google-colaboratory

I have seen that Google Colab will disconnect you if you are idle. However I have not seen a definition of idle.

If a cell is running is the user considered idle? For example if I am training a model and leave my computer will Colab disconnect me for idleness while the cell is running (assuming I don’t get disconnected for other reasons)

Also would closing my computer interrupt the notebook and disconnect me, or would the computation continue to run on their end?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).